# How to make complex multi-leg flight reservations?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, children

I want to travel to USA to get my grandchildren 
Take them to Ireland.
Then my daughter is coming home and all 3 will travel back home together.
How do I book the tickets and does the children’s names have to go on my ticket.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  You're probably best off talking to a travel agent, who can sort this out for you.

Comment: The question is not about constructing an itinerary, but about how to book that combination of flights with different passengers travelling together on the various flights. Definitely not off-topic here.

Comment: To me, this looks like a job for a travel agent, but not because it is constructing an itinerary. The OP needed help describing some very specific travel. I have suggested one answer, but there may be better ways of doing it. It should be open for more answers.

Comment: I’m a pretty seasoned traveller but booking this itinerary myself would stress me out! I’d recommend letting a travel agent take the strain

Answer (score 8):

It looks as though there are four days on which travel will happen:

- Day 1: You travel Ireland->USA
- Day 2: You and grandchildren travel USA->Ireland
- Day 3: Daughter travels USA->Ireland
- Day 4: Daughter and the grandchildren travel Ireland->USA.

If I have that right, you need several round trip tickets:

- Ireland->USA->Ireland, outbound Day 1, return Day 2, for yourself.
- USA->Ireland->USA, outbound Day 2, return Day 4, for each grandchild
- USA->Ireland->USA, outbound Day 3, return Day 4, for your daughter.

A travel agent should be able to set all this up, and do seat assignments so that the grandchildren can sit with you on Day 2, and with your daughter on Day 4. It is a bit more complicated than I would recommend trying to book yourself.

Assuming the grandchildren are under 18, do check into requirements, both USA and Ireland, for permission for minors to travel with one parent or with a non-parent relative.